# Dynamically creating nodes in a jstree tree structure

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have to retrieve a list of menu item from a database and display it in a tree structure
 I want to use the menu name as the node name and menu id as the id of the node.
The method I used was to retrieve the data using an ajax call and put them into a list and then display it as a tree.But I think dynamically creating nodes depending on the data is more efficient.

```
   function createNodeList(){
        $('#menuCPanel #contentData #tree').jstree({            
            "json_data" : {
                /*"data" : [{
                    "data" : {title : "menuName"},
                    "attr" : {id : "menuId"},
                    "state" : "closed"
                    }
                   ],*/
                 "ajax" :{
                    "type" : "POST",
                    "url" : "?m=admin?action=getNodeList",
                    "dataType" : "json",
                    "data" : function(result){
                        return {                            
                            id : result.attr ? result.attr("id") : result['menuId'],
                            title : result.attr ? result.attr("title") : result['menuName']
                        };
                    },  

                },
            },
            "callback" : {

            },

            "themes" : {
                "theme" : "classic",
                "dots" : true,
                "icons" : true
            },
            "plugins" : ["json_data", "themes"]

        }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert(jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "jstree").id) });

    }


    }
```

this is the stucture of my json data

```
"data":[{"menuId":"1","menuName":"Top Menu"},{"menuId":"2","menuName":"Main Menu"},{"menuId":"3","menuName":"Bottom Menu"},{"menuId":"4","menuName":"Main Menu"}]}
```

I would like to know what is wrong with the above result and how to dynamically create a node within in the ajax.success();
I went through some examples but all of them use the jstree.cretate() which i can't invoke inside jstree.json_data.ajax.success()
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you trying to build the tree again in the success function? Make the call to your server, the json string is returned and the tree built for you. If you want you <a> tags to go somewhere just bind the select_node.jstree

Comment: oh ok....
well I'm bit confused in this matter.can u explain bit more specifically how to display the nodes retrieved by the data{action:'getNodeList'}

Comment: Your ?m=admin should return a json string in the format described in the documentation. You don't need to create a success or error function or alter the json once passed back from ?m=admin. The ajax data received from the server is set by the tree itself into the correct format.

Comment: k i changed it but then it gives an error "Unable to initialize [Unable to initialize module (admin?action=getNodeList)]" witha a loading symbol on my page.this is the change i made
"ajax" :{ 
"type" : "POST", 
"url" : "?m=admin?action=getNodeList",
"dataType" : "json",
"data" : function(result){
 return {       
id : result.attr ? result.attr("id") : result['menuId'],
title : result.attr ? result.attr("title") : result['menuName']
};
},

Comment: Edit your answer, and add the json string you return from the server. I'll post an answer below containing the structure of one of my simple trees

Comment: ok.I edited my post.I guess then the problem should be in my json_data format

Comment: That's not the correct json structure for jstree (I don't think it's valid json at all). Look at http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data and follow the format and process set out by the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard jstree with json data, which also binds `select_node` to do actions when a node is selected. Nodes must not have an ID which are plain numbers or contain jquery special selector characters. Number IDs must have a standard character first. so 1 should be N1, 2 should be N2 for example.

```
$('#MyTreeDiv').jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "ajax": {
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "/MyServerPage.aspx?Action=GetNodes",
                "data": function (n) { return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0} },
            }
        },
        "themes": {
            "theme": "default",
            "url": "/Content/Styles/JSTree.css",
            "dots": false
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm"]
    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        var selectedObj = data.rslt.obj;
        alert(selectedObj.attr("id"));
});
```

The json returned from your server must be in the correct format as defined in the jstree documentation, and must no include several special characters, unless those characters are escaped or the json created using serialization.

Comment: ok thanks Byron.can u explain what is done with the function
"data": function (n) { return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0} },
            }

Comment: It checks if a node(n) is selected, if yes then pass its id(n.attr("id") to the server else pass 0 to the server.

Comment: It checks if a node(n) is selected, if yes then pass its id(n.attr("id") to the server else pass 0 to the server.

Comment: ok thanks alot Cobb.thanks for ur great help
nw it's partially working.just have to work on my json data format